# Context change events won't work Meteor

Tags: javascript, events, meteor

So i've got a structure like this

```
<template name="example">

{{#each post}}
<div class="hello"></div>
{{/each}}

</template>
```

So now I am trying to check for click events on the `hello` div like so

```
Template.example.events = {
  'click .hello' : function(event) {

     console.log("hey");

  }    
}
```

But this is not working. Console is not logging anything.

Does this have to do anything with the change of context in the html template?

Comment: Which javascript template engine you are using..?

Comment: Handlebars bundled with Meteor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`events` is a function that you need to pass an event map to. Right now you are assigning an event map and overriding the actual `events` method. Try this:

```
Template.example.events({
  'click .hello' : function(event) {
     console.log("hey");
  }    
});
```

Comment: I see that's now what the documentation shows. However, I do have old code that's done the way I've shown in my post and that's working. 

Anyway, changing it to this format seems to have worked. Thanks :)